# React prevent middle click from scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I prevent the middle mouse (wheel) click from scrolling? I want it to close a tab instead.

I've seen several posts on how to do it with a normal javascript event, but I'm doing this in react and `stopPropagation`, `preventDefault` and `return false` from the event handler doesn't do it.

Here is a tiny example of roughly what my code looks like.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    handleMouseUp = e => {
        if (e.nativeEvent.button === 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: which event handler are you using? can you use a mousedown/up?

Comment: I don't think it is related with being vanilla JS or React. How are you registering the function?

Comment: I've tried both `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp`. I added some example code.

Comment: My browser is an electron app.

Comment: Have you tried other event listeners? check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343277/how-do-i-suppress-window-mouse-wheel-scrolling)

Comment: `onScroll` and `onWheel` don't get called.

Comment: I'm fine with disabling the middle mouse cardinal scroll for the entire app/site.

Comment: Looks like I can do it completely outside of react it will work. `document.body.onmousedown = e => { if (e.button === 1) return false; };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to do it inside react. I was able to do it globally like this though.

```
document.body.onmousedown = e => { if (e.button === 1) return false; };
```

I'm doing this in a `componentDidMount` on the outer most component.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible sources of error here. First try binding `handleMouseUp` to `this` in the call to it within the div: `this.handleMouseUp.bind(this)`. You may also try using `onMouseDown` instead. That will precent the event before it has the chance to happen.